# How to access the rows before and after a pivot row (can be any row) using a loop in a PHP script working on a mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

The following code queries the database for every row preceding the pivot row using 'for' loop in php script. Same is the case with querying all the folowing rows. This code is not optimized as everytime a new query is injected into sql. Is there any technique that can speed up the whole process? Is there any query in mysql that can solve the purpose and using which the loop can be bypassed?

```
    while($speed < 3 && $found > 0)
    {
        $sub_query = "select * from sheet_17_43_2 where Generation = ". $found ."-1";
        $res = mysql_query($sub_query);

        if (!$res) 
        {
            echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
            exit;
        }

        if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) 
        {
                echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
            exit;
        }
        $speed = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)["Speed"];
        mysql_free_result($res);
        $time++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare the current value of a column (`col`) to the 'previous' value, do something like

```
SELECT  t.col - @prev AS change_from_prev,
        @prev := t.col
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  @prev := 0 ) initializer
    JOIN  t
    ORDER BY  ...
```

The `ORDER BY` is important.